# Adding hardcoded value to contentSize

Tags: objective-c, xcode, lvalue, contentsize

I've been trying to make my scrollview correctly fit it's content which includes a label, UIImageView, and textview. The textview sizes dynamically to different text, so I've made the scrollview's content size the same as the textview's:

```
sview.contentSize = (tview.contentSize);
```

That worked as expected, so my scrollview is close to the size I want, but I need to just add a static 180 pixels or so to make up for the label and image, which don't change size. I would guess it's an easy 1 or 2 lines of code but I can't figure it out. I've tried:

```
sview.contentSize += 180;
```

and

```
CGRect extra;
extra.size.height = 180;
sview.contentSize += extra.size;
```

and several other combinations to try to make it work but I keep getting errors like Lvalue required as left operand of assignment, or invalid operands to binary +. I'm sure I'm missing an easy solution, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(sview.contentSize.width, sview.contentSize.height+180);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! That looks good, but it's telling me that CGSize has no member named 'origin'.

Comment: Actually after looking at it again, it says it has no member named 'origin' or 'size' and "incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setContentSize:'

Comment: ah, i've edited it to fix it..didn't realize it was a CGSize struct not a CGRect.

Comment: Yep that did the trick, except you don't need(and can't have) the .size attributes after the ".contentSize"s. Change that and your answer is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: yep. early in the morning woes. hah.